# Runtime class override with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I created a custom File based on `java.io.File` as such I have:

`class CloudFile extends java.io.File {}`

Is it possible with ByteBuddy to (at runtime) be able to replace all calls to the class `java.io.File` and *masquerade* it with the new `CloudFile`

So, for example I created an app that uses a library that extensively uses `java.io.File` what I want is any call of that library to the `File` class in my application would be a call to `CloudFile`

Or otherwise, a much more plausible solution, to use ByteBuddy to create a Classloader that will override the `java.io.File` -- and the question is what is the right take on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine classes using a Java agent which Byte Buddy allows building with an `AgentBuilder`. You can then instruct it to redefine all your library code where you replace constructor calls to `File` with your `CloudFile` which I assume has virtual overrides for the methods in question.

In order to replace a constructor, create a transformer that registers a `MemberSubstitution` where the constructor is switched out.

Comment: So meaning, for this example class https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/entity-store/src/main/java/jetbrains/exodus/entitystore/FileSystemBlobVault.java I can basically use ByteBuddy to make the File calls here replaced by the class I want?

Comment: Yes, Byte Buddy would take the constructor call and replace it with a call to CloudFile, given that a compatible constructor exists.